# Get active position on angular cdk overlay?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

> Is there a way to get in the attached component to an overlay the
>   active position ? For exaple I say to a tooltip to open above but this
>   cannot be done and the overlay will open it below. I want to add an
>   arrow pointing to my element from the tooltip and I need to now if the
>   overlay is above/below the element to position the arrow correctly

Answer (score 7):

**ConnectedPositionStrategy** (deprecated) has **onPositionChange** property and
**FlexibleConnectedPositionStrategy** has **positionChanges** property, we can not subscribe to this observables before the overlay is created, so, the solution is to subscribe after overlay is created:

```js
const positionStrategy = this.overlay
        .position()
        .flexibleConnectedTo(this.selectHeader)
        .withPositions([
         {
            originX: 'start',
            originY: 'bottom',
            overlayX: 'start',
            overlayY: 'top',
          },
          {
            originX: 'start',
            originY: 'top',
            overlayX: 'start',
            overlayY: 'bottom',
          },
        ]);
    this.panelOverlay = this.overlay.create({positionStrategy});
    positionStrategy.positionChanges.subscribe(pos => console.log(pos));
```

Comment: It's not good enough, if the overlay gets pushed from its side, the origin might be off, so calculation is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

You can use "panelClass" as below:

```
return new OverlayConfig({
  hasBackdrop: true,
  positionStrategy: this.overlay.position()
    .flexibleConnectedTo(new ElementRef(mouseEvent.target))
    .withFlexibleDimensions(false)
    .withPositions([
      {
        originX: 'start',
        originY: 'top',
        overlayX: 'start',
        overlayY: 'top',
        panelClass: 'top' <--
      },
      {
        originX: 'start',
        originY: 'bottom',
        overlayX: 'start',
        overlayY: 'bottom',
        panelClass: 'bottom' <--
      }
    ])
})
```

[image: Result]